# 'Appearance' icon not showing in 'System Settings'

Tags: system-settings

I am facing a very peculiar problem, the 'Appearance' icon in 'System settings' has disappeared and now I cannot change the background or control the unity. Any ideas how to get it back?

Comment: Could you take a screenshoot of the *System settings* menu? You can upload it in [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and link it into your question editing it.

Comment: Along with screen shot also explain your last activity what you remember that may affect appearance. Before that check in Ubuntu software center weather the **"appearance"** was ticked(installed) or not. You may have uninstalled appearance accidentally.

Comment: @learner Make your comment an answer. It perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0):

Along with screen shot as lucio said, also explain your last activity what you remember that may affect **appearance**. Before that check in Ubuntu software center weather the "**appearance**" was ticked(installed) or not. You may have uninstalled **appearance** accidentally.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be something Gnome has changed, since I am not using Unity (sticking to Gnome-Shell) and the same happens to me.

You will find another Icon under the System Settings (I am not sure how stuff is called because the default of my system is not in English) called Background. You can also access it clicking on the desktop with the right mouse button and choosing "Change Background".